# Automatically upload new files added in multiple directories to FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am trying to do some automation in uploading new files to FTP that were added in local directories to the same directories in server.

Is there anyway I could make that possible? Please help me out. I will be grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: It was not supposed to be tagged for Java script. Edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use any command-line Windows FTP client that supports synchronization.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), you can use its [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "synchronize remote c:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

And depending on your requirements, either loop the batch file or [schedule it in Windows scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

For real-time synchronization, you can also use the [`keepuptodate` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

```
winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "keepuptodate c:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I will try with winscp, Thank you so much.